# Angular: Display image from blob

Tags: angular

having trouble getting my image to show.. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

```
 <img style="width:175px" [src]="imageToShow">


getImage(){
  this.mccProgramService.getImageFromService().subscribe(
    (res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.imageToShow = res;
    //  window.open(fileURL);
    }
  );
}

getImageFromService() {
        return this._httpClient.get("http://localhost:9080/mccr/api/file/download.action?contentFileId=11", {observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'})
          .map((res) => {
            return new Blob([res.body], {type: res.headers.get('Content-Type')});
          })
      }
```

Data is coming back as this from service

```
<<other headers>>
<<Content-Type header>>
<<other headers>>
<<file binary data>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have blob image value, you can directly set the value in image tag..

```
<img  src="data:image/png;base64,{{blobData}}"/>
```

I have tried it in angular7, its working..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object URL for the blob:

```
this.imageToShow = URL.createObjectURL(res);
```

UPDATE

Also, if you set the `responseType` to blob then you will get back a blob so you can remove the map statement entirely in `getImageFromService`

Comment: Added another suggestion

Comment: WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value blob:https://localhost:4200/d43b3a76-cbc0-45f5-97a2-48a9ef50751f (see https://g.co/ng/security#xss)

Answer (score 0):

Your `.ts` file -

```
YourMethod().subscribe((blob : any) => { this.blobdata = blob.fileContents; }
```

Your `.html` file -

```
< img  src="data:image/png;base64,{{blobData}}"/>
```

Your `c# endpoint` should `return Ok(File(model.Byte, "image/jpeg"));`

I hope it helps. And thank you, Deepa, your suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img  src="data:image/png;base64,{{data_base64}}"/>
```

Comment: Copy of accepted answer with a trivial refactor.